# What are some ways to compile Java from C# code?

Tags: c#, javac

I'm writing a multi-language IDE in C#. Right now, it works as a reasonably functional editor. However, I'm working now on adding the ability to compile and run Java code (I know it sounds silly to write this in C#, but I prefer using C#, and I need the Java support for a school class).

After that background, here is the question: What is the best way to compile Java code from C#? Right now, I am using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class. Basically, I am invoking the compiler the same way you would call javac from the command line. Here is a rough example of my current implementation:

```
ProcessStartInfo buildInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
buildInfo.WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(sourcePath);
buildInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
buildInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
buildInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process buildProcess = Process.Start(buildInfo);
```

I redirect standard output and error because later the application catches them to determine whether the compilation was successful. Is there a better way to do this? It feels a little sloppy, and I wanted to know if I was overlooking something.

Comment: What is the IDE?? You most likely do not need to go so far as to write a c# program to run cmd line compiler tools. Most likely, the IDE supports the ability to run custom cmd line commands with params and the whole nine yards. This would allow you to compile your java code with the java compiler.

Comment: @MatthewCox He is writing his own IDE so he is basically building the custom commandline stuff for it right now.

Comment: doh, i missed the first two words `I'm writing a` ... somehow i interpretted that as `I'm writing in a`.

Comment: Now I see the reason for the close vote. ... Honestly, I would strongly urge you to stop this. In a professional environment, you won't have this luxury of just deciding that you want a custom IDE to make things more convenient ... (if they even would ever eventually amount to convenient) and you are in every sense of the phrase "reinventing the wheel".

Comment: The IDE isn't just about convenience - it's a learning experience. I realize that I won't be able to write an IDE just because I don't like the ones at hand - this is a simple pet project that is helping me learn. It also needs specific characteristics that I can't get in other mainstream Java IDEs.

Comment: I included the information about the project as background; however, I still believe this is a relevant question, even if it's only useful in uncommon scenarios.

Comment: I think people will reopen this if it gets closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have other options. Java provides JNI (Java Native Interface ) which allows Java to call native code **and** apropos, for native code to call Java (albeit in a rather complex way.)

Depending on how much of a learning experience you want this to be you can use JNI directly or use a library such as jni4net. A different interop approach is to use ikvm which is a jvm running inside the clr, but I don't think it'll be useful to you as it does not include a compiler.

You can also research alternative compilers such as gcj or ejc.

Not having tried to write an IDE I don't know whether these approaches are actually better than using the command line directly. My hunch is that for simple integration the command line is the easier to use however more complex scenarios, e.g. incremental compilation of large projects with multiple components, may require tighter integration.

If you plan on providing features such as inline debugging and error highlighting while you type you're going to require tighter integration anyway.

IDEs are extremely complex programs, even mere programming editors are complex enough.

Comment: This is probably the most helpful answer I've received so far. My program already partially supports GCJ, the issue was more of how to support the JVM properly. jni4net is definitely something I was looking for, I did not think something like it existed. 

About my IDE: it's a relatively simple IDE. In fact, I'm trying to be as minimalist as possible, and to leave out everything that is not totally necessary. Compilation and running does fall under this category, as does syntax highlighting, code folding, etc. It is a complex project indeed, one that I have been working on for years.

Answer (score 2):

A quick googling suggests (no surprise) there's no .Net API for compiling Java.  Thus, the simplest way will probably be to use `javac` via the command line, as you are currently doing.

Your command line code looks similar to examples I've seen, so I don't expect there's much room for improvement.  Thus, the short answer to your question: no, you're good (as good as compiling Java from C# can be, anyway).

Comment: Yes, I've looked around on Google checking, but thank you. I wanted to see if anyone else had any ideas that I may have missed.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [Java Invocation API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html) to host the JVM within your process and then run the compiler through the [compiler API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html). It's probably faster than spinning up separate compiler process for compilation and certainly makes for a good learning experience (you'd need to use P/Invoke from the .NET side etc.).

Comment: Actually, I hadn't even thought of that. You are certainly right about being a learning process, but that's definitely something I'll consider.

Answer (score 0):

There are some free and commercial tools out there:
http://community.versant.com/Blogs/db4o/tabid/197/entryid/94/Default.aspx
http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9789645d-9b31-4033-bcb1-53dc5ff58e05

And so forth...

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't what I'm asking. I don't need to convert the source code; I want to compile the Java source code as is to the Java platform.